# change all posted data in zend

Tags: zend-framework, xss, html-entities

I want to apply this function to all posted data in zend frame work to prevent XSS attacks.

```
static function safe_against_xss($argument) {

    $HtmlEntities_Filter = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities ( array ('quotestyle' => NULL, 'charset' => 'UTF-8' ) );
    $argument = $HtmlEntities_Filter->filter ( $argument );
    return $argument;
}
```

I use this code in my controller

```
            $requests = $request->getPost() ;

            foreach ($requests as $key => $value)
            {
                $requests[$key]=Functions::safe_against_xss($value);
            }
```

It's worked,but i want to apply this function to all posted data in all controllers. automatically.

Sincerely

Comment: Automatically? do you need to apply this validation to every control result with out actually adding this code?

Comment: Yes,I won't write this code for all controllers.

Comment: Isn't this automatically done by the request handler? If it is your function will be an unnecessary overhead on top of every request.

Answer (score 0):

I write this codes:

```
$this->setRequest(Functions::safe_request($this->getRequest()));
```

In init of controllers

Then in Functions:

```
     static function safe_against_xss($argument) {
    // $HtmlEntities_Filter = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities ( NULL, 'UTF-8'
    // );
    $HtmlEntities_Filter = new Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities ( array ('quotestyle' => NULL, 'charset' => 'UTF-8' ) );
    if (is_array($argument))
    {
        foreach($argument as $key => $value) {
            $argument[$key] = $HtmlEntities_Filter->filter ( $value );
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $argument = $HtmlEntities_Filter->filter ( $argument );
    }
    return $argument;
}

static  function safe_post_params($params)
{
    $safePostParams = array();
    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        $safePostParams[$key] = self::safe_against_xss($value);
    }
    return $safePostParams;
}

static  function safe_request($params)
{
    $params->setParams(Functions::safe_post_params($params->getParams()));
    $params->setPost(Functions::safe_post_params($params->getPost()));
    return $params;
}
```